# How to correctly read the diacritics in TCPDF?

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I made a pdf file with TCPDF and the problem is that the romanian characters aren't read correctly. For example, `ţă` is `Å£Äƒ`. The charset of the pdf is utf-8.

How can I get TCPDF to correctly read these characters?

Comment: How are you outputting the characters?

Comment: In my text editor (SUBLIME) are shown corectly("ţă") in the problem is when I open the pdf in browser ...

Comment: The PDF format does not natively support UTF-8. What you are getting in your PDF are un-parsed UTF-8 characters. Check your library for any encoding options.

Answer (score 0):

If you want characters of a particular type to come up, you need to do two things. Firstly, you need to make sure that the font you are using contains those characters. Secondly, you need to make sure you are using the right Unicode numbers that refer to the appropriate characters in the font.

If you are using a UTF8-aware editor then the second part should be a no-brainer - generally speaking, whatever you type into the editor will get saved in the code, the code will run and that same string will get included in the PDF file. What can potentially derail things is the first part. The problem is that many fonts have a two byte character encoding, whereas some Postscript fonts (which is what TCPDF and some of the font conversion web sites create), only have a one-byte encoding, which means you only get a 255 byte subset of the font. So you might be using a TrueType or OpenType font and thinking that all the characters will be available in the PDF, but they might not, as they might not be in the font file that TCPDF needs.

I highly recommend using the popular FontForge application to inspect the font you are using in TCPDF, as this will show you exactly what characters are included in the font and what the respective code points are.